# JsonLoader missing from Piggybank

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig

ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.JsonLoader using imports...

When i look at pig-0.12.1/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/ there is indeed no JsonLoader.java.

Can it be added or is there a 'correct' piggybank I can download?

TIA!!

I'm using:
Apache Pig version 0.12.2-SNAPSHOT (r: unknown) 
compiled Apr 15 2014, 20:35:46

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the correct location is `org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonLoader`.  You shouldn't need the package path at all though.

Comment: Thanks! I should have had USING org.apache.pig.builtin.JsonLoader(
not
USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.JsonLoader(